# Plotting data from CSV file that has been filtered

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am aiming to create a program which can plot sales data (not for a real company). The dataset I have is pretty large so I tried filtering it so only one product is shown, there is duplications of each item so there is still quite a few.

After filtering the data I can not seem to get to plot it. I have tried numerous different methods however none have worked. I am very new to pandas and matplotlib so any help would be appreciated.

```py
def graph(data): # Represents certain data as a graph
        
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
    plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

   
    datac = pd.read_csv("Task3_data.csv")  # Reads data

    keyword = "Lettuce"
    column_name = "Product"
    
    filtered_df = datac[datac[column_name].str.contains(keyword, case=False, na=False)] # Filters data so only lettuce data is shown 
    
    plt.plot(filtered_df.KGs_Sold, filtered_df.KGs_Purchased)
    plt.show

graph(data)
```

`KGs_Sold` and `KGs_Purchased` are both columns I am wishing to plot. I could not find anything online to aid me doing this so if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated, I will attach a photo of my data to help gather a general idea.

[Picture of CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGchP.png)

Comment: It's hard to understand what kind of plot are you expecting here.  Maybe `plt.plot(filtered_df['Date'], filtered_df['KGs_Purchased'])` and `plt.plot(filtered_df['Date'], filtered_df['KGs_Sold'])`? Supposing the `Date` column is in the DateTime format.

Comment: Could you add test data as text? Having it as image is strongly frowned upon  at StackOverflow.  E.g. add the output of `print(filtered_df.to_dict(orient='list'))`.

Comment: That also does not work, I get an error on filtered_df where it says collumn_name and all it says on the error is 'product'

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35710741) your question and add the full error trace? Pandas doesn't have error messages that only say 'product'. Anyway, without a test version of the dataframe, it is hard to know what is going on. Could you also clearly describe what kind of output you are expecting? What is on the x-axis and what on the y-axis?  Is that `KGs_Sold` on the x-axis and `KGs_Purchased` on the y-axis?

Answer (score 0):

The example below works for a dataset that's similar to yours. It scatter plots the two columns after filtering by `keyword`.

Note that if the data is missing `"Lettuce"` it would result in an empty plot.

Test data:

```py
    Product KGs_Purchased   KGs_Sold
0   Peas    6.692863502084602   5.861591681351845
1   Oranges 13.40041570647459   7.865275844481289
2   Carrots 2.564579797199695   0.9015340456777049
3   Carrots 6.564341659704407   3.9147955343374834
4   Lettuce ...
```

[image]

Imports and create some test data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Create test dataset
# data = pd.read_csv("Task3_data.csv")  # Reads data
np.random.seed(0)
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': np.random.choice(['Oranges', 'Lemons', 'Lettuce', 'Carrots', 'Peas'], 300),
    'KGs_Purchased': np.random.uniform(0.1, 1.2, 300) * 20, 
}).assign(KGs_Sold=lambda df: df.KGs_Purchased * 0.7 + np.random.randn(300))
```

The modified `graph()` function:

```py
#Plotting function
def graph(data): # Represents certain data as a graph
    keyword = "Lettuce"
    column_name = "Product"
    
    filtered_df = data[data[column_name].str.contains(keyword, case=False, na=False)] # Filters data so only lettuce data is shown 
    
    plt.scatter(filtered_df.KGs_Sold, filtered_df.KGs_Purchased)
    plt.xlabel('KGs_Sold')
    plt.ylabel('KGs_Purchased')
    plt.title('Filtering by ' + column_name + '=' + keyword)
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 3)
    plt.show()

#Usage:
graph(data)
```